# Is earth acceleration constantly affecting?

Tags: gravity, acceleration

If we define $F = ma$, and we assume that in every moment an object is suffering the effects of gravity ($F= 9.8 N/kg$), can we asume that an object in earth is continuously under an acceleration? Is that true even keeping in mind that the object is not moving due to the normal generated by (for example) the floor?

As I see it, if the addition of all forces (gravity + Normal) = 0, the acceleration has to be defined as 0, but on the other hand, the gravity can be defined as an acceleration of $9.8 m/s^2$. This would mean that there is always acceleration even though the object is not moving.

I'm kind of confused about this. Any help? Thanks

Comment: "we [...] assume the complete physical equivalence of a gravitational field and a corresponding acceleration of the reference system." -  Einstein, 1907

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really get the meaning of this sentence. Can you explain it a bit? Thanks

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle

Comment: Again, I'm struggling to get the meaning of this principle (I'm a noob in phisics v.v). Does it simply means that gravity == acceleration?

Comment: The effects of gravity are equivalent to acceleration, but only locally in a small region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a net acceleration, there's movement. (However, movement doesn't imply acceleration).

Your point is correct, when you're on the surface, there're two main forces acting on you, gravity and normal. Since you're at rest on radial component (I assume you're not jumping), the radial net force should be zero, and, therefore, the net acceleration in this direction is also $0$.

Comment: But if we separate both forces, we have a gravity force and a normal force. If we take each of them separately, we can see that Fg (Force of Gravity) = m*ag (acceleration of the gravity) => ag = Fg/m. Therefore, as there is always a gravity force, there is always a gravity acceleration. Is it true?

Comment: There's always gravity acceleration that's true. However, there's always also a "normal acceleration", with the same magnitude and opposite direction, so the sum of both acceleartions is zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you say that "we define $F=ma$, you must say what is defined and what is used to define it. Sometimes, the notation $:=$ is used, for example: $R:=\frac{U}{I}$. The resistance is defined by the ratio of voltage to current.

One can define for example $a := \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$

If you write $F := ma$ it is perhaps more helpful to read it as $\vec F_{\text{sum}} := m\vec a$. The sum of all forces leads to an acceleration in the direction of the sum of the forces.

There may be several forces (e.g. due to gravity and some surface "pushing back") acting on the same body that add up to $\vec 0$ and no acceleration occurs.

On earth, there always is the force $F_g = 9.81\frac{\text{N}}{\text{kg}} \cdot m$ downwards but for all objects resting (or moving horizontally) on a surface, a force of the same magnitude acts in upward direction.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.There is always acceleration and you rotate with the earth. If it happens that your mobile phone has an accelerometer on board you will see something about 1g or 9.8 m/s^2 along z-axes. It is why we are rotating whit Earth and cannot travel by waiting for our destination to rise at west.